# how to implement PHP session manually

Tags: php, session, cookies, manual

I am new to PHP. I want to implement PHP session manually. On a PHP pageload, I will check if cookie is set. If yes, I will display the required information, and if not, I will ask user to enter his details and then display the information. But I am not allowed to use PHP Sessions. I can use Cookies. Also the information needed to be displayed is about all the users (browsers) who are in session (so I have to save this to some static global array). Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: read this http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-To-PHP-Sessions.html you will get clear cut idea of session... and you will get your all answers there only

Comment: If the PHP is running as CGI, you will have no global array, at least at application level. You can use a database server with a temporary table (on RAM), to store session data, its only one of the options.

Comment: "But I am not allowed to use PHP Sessions." - why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
setcookie('cookie_name', 'cookie_value', time());
echo $_COOKIE['cookie_name'];
```

Now check the cookie if it exists.

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['cookie_name'])) {
    echo "your cookie is set";
} else {
    echo "return error or any thing you want";
}
```

This will give you all browser(s) information.

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```