# how to implement session with php

Tags: php, angularjs, session

I'm developing an AngularJs application with PHP backend, I implemented the authentication step, and now I'm trying to display data of authenticated user in another view after authentication.

I used session token to display user data in other view but Even if I did what I read in some tutorials about sessions and tokens more than two weeks, I still can't display user data. And I get this error in display.php file:

> Undefined index: token

I can't progress in my application. I'm working with sessions.

login.php

```
<?php  
session_start();
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database");  

 if(count($data) > 0)  

 { 

$Email=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->Email);
$password=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->password);

$query = 'SELECT * FROM `client` WHERE (EmailClient = "'.$Email.'" AND   password= "'.$password.'")';

$q = mysqli_query($connect , $query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0 )
  { 
       $token = md5($Email.time()."51395+81519851");
       $query = "UPDATE client SET token = '".$token."' WHERE EmailClient = '".$Email."'";
       mysqli_query($connect , $query);
       $_SESSION["logged_in"] = true; 
       $_SESSION["token"] = $token; 
       $result['message'] ='Logged In';
       $result['email'] =$Email;
       $result['token'] = $token;

       $resultstring=json_encode($result);
       $resultstring=str_replace("null", '""', $resultstring);
       echo $resultstring;
       exit;
  }

       $result['message'] ='The username or password are incorrect!';

$resultstring = json_encode($result);
$resultstring = str_replace("null",'""',$resultstring);
echo $resultstring;
exit;
}

?>
```

display.php

```
<?php  
session_start();
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database");  

 $output = array();  
 $query = "SELECT Name,Adresse FROM client WHERE token = '".$_SESSION['token']."'";
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
 {  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {  
           $output[] = $row;  
      }  
      echo json_encode($output);  
 }  

 ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to implement PHP session manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605474/how-to-implement-php-session-manually)

Comment: try to print `$_SESSION` and check that is session set or not.

Comment: Valentin! No , I m working with sessions not cookies. Thank you

Comment: @SonuBamniya I get this error: Array to string conversion

Comment: user `print_r($_SESSION)` or `var_dump($_SESSION)` instead of `echo`

Comment: I receive all users except those whose token is established, And I always get this error: Undefined index: token .

Comment: and when I click on login , I get nothing